# List as IQueryCollection returns null

Tags: c#

The following code sets something as null. How can I convert effectively from a List to an IQueryCollection or instantiate something that implements IQueryCollection out of the box.

```
var queryStringParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>("filter.limit", "1")
};

var something = queryStringParams as IQueryCollection;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? [IQueryCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iquerycollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is a specialized ASP.NET Core interface that represents the query parameters: `Represents the HttpRequest query string collection`. No generic collection implements this. You shouldn't need to use it in your own methods either. If you want to mock `IQueryCollection` you could create a class that implements this yourself or use a mocking framework.

Comment: Even for mocking, it would be strange to mock that interface. If you want to run integration tests with your ASP.NET Core application you can use [ASP.NET Core's TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1)